# processing very small file with hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have a question about using hadoop to process a small file. My file only has about a 1,000 or so records but i want the records to roughly be evenly distributed among the nodes. Is there a way to do this? I'm new to hadoop and so far it seems that all the execution is happening on one node instead a multiple simultaneously. Let me know if my question makes sense or if I need to clarify anything. Like I said, i'm very new to Hadoop but am hoping to get some clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [NLineInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/NLineInputFormat.html) and specify the number of records to be processed by each mapper. This way the records in a single block will be processed by multiple mappers.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, so will using the NLineInputFormat override the values set for mapred.max.split.size and dfs.block.size?

Comment: I don't think it considers the mapred.max.split.size and dfs.block.size into consideration. Please check [NLineInputFormat.java](http://goo.gl/mAFbK) code for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to split your one input file into multiple input files (in the one input path directory).
Each of those input files will then be able to be spread across the hdfs and the map
operations will occur on the worker machines that own those input splits.